# Comparing two excel sheets, same workbook, highlight differences

Tags: excel, vba

I am doing my first steps in excel 2007 vba. What I am trying to do is to code a macro that compares my last and my second last excel sheet and highlights the differences in the last one. As you can see below I coded the following and Excel does not display any errors when I use the debug mode, yet it does not mark any cells where a change has been made, which it is suppose to do. Would anyone mind having a look and correct my potential mistakes in the code below. Thank you very much.

```
Sub compare()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
Dim rCount As Long, cCount As Long
Set sh1 = Worksheets(Sheets.Count - 1)
Set sh2 = Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
rCount = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
cCount = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim r As Long, c As Integer
For r = 1 To rCount
    For c = 1 To cCount
        If sh1.Cells(r, c) <> sh2.Cells(r, c) Then
           sh2.Cells(r, c).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Next c
Next r
```

End Sub

Comment: Your cCount is the same as rCount but that does not explain cells not being marked. Have you tested what value you have for rCount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you only have a single row of data in sh1. When you assign rcount you get a value of 1 and when you assign cCount you are getting THE SAME VALUE because you are assigning it the same way as rcount. You then probably iterate through a single row and a single column, comparing only a single cell and then the subroutine exits.

Perhaps you mean: `cCount = sh1.Cells(1, ColumnsCount).End(xltoLeft).Column`

Comment: The advise with rows and Columns was correct. Thank you! The Marco works with defined names for sh1 and sh2. But those names are dynamic and somehow with my code the last and second last sheets are not used. Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure why the dynamic 'last sheet' logic isn't working. I've never seen that used before, but there is a lot I haven't seen so I figured it was right for your situation. You might want to consider a common sheet naming convention like 'DataSheet1', 'DataSheet2', etc. Then you could loop through your sheets and pick off Right(Worksheet.name, 1) to determine which sheet was the "last".